# Update table with Left Join

Tags: sql, db2

How do I update table with a left join on the script.  I'm using a DB2 database.

I created a select statement and it works:

**

```
select  t1.estrcd as "transaction code",
        t1.espyno as "payer",
        t1.escuno as "customer no",
        t1.escino as "invoice no",
        t1.esvono as "voucher no",
        t1.escuam as "foreign currency amount",
        COALESCE(t2."received_amount",0) as "received amount",
        t1.escuam + COALESCE(t2."received_amount",0) as "outstanding amount"
from m3edbedu.fsledg t1 left join
        (select espyno, escino, sum(escuam) as "received_amount" from m3edbedu.fsledg
                where estrcd = 20 group by espyno, escino) as t2 on
        t2.espyno = t1.espyno and t2.escino = t1.escino
where t1.esreco = 0 and t1.estrcd = 10 and (t1.escuam + COALESCE(t2."received_amount",0)) = 0
order by t1.espyno, t1.escino, t1.estrcd;
```

**

but now they ask me to update the table and set the t1.esreco to 9.  I tried using the below script to update but I'm getting an error.

```
update m3edbedu.fsledg t1 LEFT JOIN(select espyno, escino, sum(escuam) as "received_amount"
           from m3edbedu.fsledg
           where estrcd = 20
           group by espyno, escino) as t2
           on t2.espyno = t1.espyno and t2.escino = t1.escino set t1.esreco = 9 where t1.esreco = 0 and t1.estrcd = 10 and (t1.escuam + COALESCE(t2."received_amount",0)) = 0 order by t1.espyno, t1.escino, t1.estrcd;1;
```

> Error: SQL0199 - Keyword LEFT not expected. Valid tokens: SET.
>   (State:37000, Native Code: FFFFFF39) Error: SQL0104 - Token 1 was not
>   valid. Valid tokens: ( CL END GET SET CALL DROP FREE HOLD LOCK OPEN
>   WITH ALTER BEGIN. (State:37000, Native Code: FFFFFF98)

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a DB2 database, you cannot specify the FROM clause in an update statement. Updated answer to reflect what you'd have to do (keep in mind this is in no way optimized).

```
update 
    m3edbedu.fsledg t1
set 
    t1.esreco = 9 
where
    t1.esreco = 0 and t1.estrcd = 10 and
    exists(select t2.espyno
        from m3edbedu.fsledg t2
        where t2.estrcd = 20 and t2.espyno = t1.espyno and t2.escino = t1.escino)
    and (t1.escuam + coalesce(
        (select sum(t2.escuam) 
        from m3edbedu.fsledg t2 
        where t2.estrcd = 20 and t2.espyno = t1.espyno and t2.escino = t1.escino), 0) = 0)
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but I'm still having the same error: Error: SQL0199 - Keyword FROM not expected. Valid tokens: SKIP WITH WHERE. (State:37000, Native Code: FFFFFF39)
Error: SQL0104 - Token 1 was not valid. Valid tokens: ( CL END GET SET CALL DROP FREE HOLD LOCK OPEN WITH ALTER BEGIN. (State:37000, Native Code: FFFFFF98)

Comment: Should've read which DB engine you were using. DB2 apparently doesn't like FROM clauses in an update statement. I'll give you an updated response shortly.

Answer (score 0):

DB2 does not support joins in an `UPDATE` statement, so you'll have to do a workaround, such as making the join part a correlated subquery, as such:

```
UPDATE m3edbedu.fsledg update
SET esreco = 9
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM m3edbedu.fsledg t1
    LEFT JOIN(
        SELECT espyno,
               escino,
               sum(escuam) as received_amount
          FROM m3edbedu.fsledg
         WHERE estrcd = 20
         GROUP BY espyno, escino
    ) as t2
    ON t2.espyno = t1.espyno
    AND t2.escino = t1.escino
    WHERE t1.unique_key1 = update.unique_key1
      AND t1.unique_key2 = update.unique_key2
      AND t1.unique_key3 = update.unique_key3
      --etc

      AND t1.esreco = 0
      AND t1.estrcd = 10
      AND (t1.escuam + COALESCE(t2.received_amount,0)) = 0
)
```

You probably want to check and make sure that you're getting the right columns from the subquery by changing the `UPDATE` part to a `SELECT`.

Comment: thank you very much for the info.  I'll try the one you mentioned and let you know what will happen.  Again, thanks. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
update t1 
SET t1.esreco = 9
from m3edbedu.fsledg t1 
LEFT JOIN ( select espyno, escino, sum(escuam) as "received_amount" 
            from m3edbedu.fsledg
            where estrcd = 20
            group by espyno, escino) as t2
on t2.espyno = t1.espyno 
and t2.escino = t1.escino 
where t1.esreco = 0 
and t1.estrcd = 10 
and (t1.escuam + COALESCE(t2."received_amount",0)) = 0 ;
```

Comment: hello... thanks for the reply but the error still exist: Error: SQL0199 - Keyword FROM not expected. Valid tokens: SKIP WITH WHERE. (State:37000, Native Code: FFFFFF39)

Comment: This is SQL server syntax